# How do you maintain the route on page reload for an angular app in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, iframe

I have an angular app loaded inside a Facebook canvas. When I refresh the page, the angular app loads the root url at `/` everytime. If I navigate to another route and I reload the page, how I maintain the state?

The libraries I am using are AngularJS and UI Router.

Here's an example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Test</title>

  </head>
<body>

  <iframe src="http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/index.html" height="1500" width="1500" frameborder="0"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a session cookie or time limited cookie, on state change save the current state - on page load check the cookie - if it exists navigate to the desired state.